# Inequality with argument of quotient of complex number

Tags: complex-numbers

Show on a complex plane:
$$\left\{ z \in \mathbb{C}: \operatorname{arg} \frac{i}{z} \leq \frac{3 \pi}{4}\right\}.$$
After some easy steps I came to:
$$-\operatorname{arg}(z) =\operatorname{arg} \overline{z} \leq \pi/4.$$
What now?

Comment: It might be easier to let $z=re^{i \theta}$ and see how the above inequality restricts $r,\theta$?

Comment: For sure $r > 0$, but I don't have any conclusion about $\theta$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $z=r e^{i \theta}$, with $r >0$ and $\theta \in [0,2 \pi)$, then $\frac{i}{z} = \frac{1}{r} e^{i(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta)}$.

Hence $\arg \frac{i}{z} = \begin{cases}\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta, & \theta \in [0,\frac{\pi}{2})\\ 2 \pi +\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta, & \theta \in [\frac{\pi}{2}, 2 \pi)\end{cases}$.

**Note**: I am using $\arg z \in [0,2 \pi)$.

**Addendum**: Using $\arg z \in [-\pi, \pi)$ instead gives:

$\arg \frac{i}{z} = \begin{cases}\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta, & \theta \in [-\frac{\pi}{2}, \pi)\\ \frac{\pi}{2}-\theta - 2 \pi, & \theta \in [-\pi,-\frac{\pi}{2})\end{cases}$.

Using this formula with $\arg z \le \frac{3}{4} \pi$ gives $\theta \in [-\pi,-\frac{\pi}{2}] \cup [-\frac{\pi}{4}, \pi)$.

Comment: Ok, I got it but I have one more question. If I understand your solution correctly, you claim that the answer is: http://speedy.sh/3EH8u/1.jpg

Simultaneously, Wolfram Alpha says differently: http://speedy.sh/DMUqQ/2.jpg and http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=arg%28i%2Fz%29+%3C%3D+3pi%2F4

Where am I making a mistake?

Comment: I just gave a formula for $\arg \frac{i}{z}$, you still need to solve the inequality and figure out what $z$ they correspond to. Also, I am unable to access the links you provided.

Comment: Another possible confusion is that I used $\arg z \in [0,2 \pi)$, some folks use $\arg z \in [-\pi,\pi)$.

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe something went wrong with these images (I can open them). I solved inequalities:
$$\frac{\pi}{2} - \theta \leq \frac{3\pi}{4}$$
$$2 \pi + \frac{\pi}{2} - \theta \leq \frac{3\pi}{4}$$
with assumptions as above and I get that:
$$0 \leq \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$$
and
$$\frac{3\pi}{4} \leq \theta \leq 2\pi.$$
Wolfram says that also:
$$\frac{\pi}{2} \leq \theta \leq \frac{3\pi}{2}.$$
Why?

Comment: When I solve I get $\theta \in [0,\frac{\pi}{2}) \cup [\frac{7\pi}{4},2 \pi)$. Keep in mind the definition of $\arg$ I used, it matters, and the $\arg$ used in your problem may be slightly different.

Comment: Also, I may have a mistake; I am checking...

Comment: Yes, I'm stupid today - I mispelled... It's:
$$\frac{7\pi}{4} \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$$
of course. So what's wrong with Wolfram's answer? Is it possible that both are correct?

Comment: Well, it is possible that Wolfram is using a different $\arg$ than I used, in which case the answer will be different.

Comment: Ok, thank You very much for patience and help. All the best! :)